# android - Помогите с разметкой

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Хочу сделать разметку в которой будет квадрат слева, квадрат справа и прямоугольник посередине на всю оставшуюся длину. Квадраты - это `ImageView`, правый должен быть с картинкой Play. **Высота нижней панели должна быть с весом 10.** Запутался вообще во всем, создал собственный `ImageView` и переопределил метод `onMeasure`, так, чтобы он возвращал длину в качестве ширины. И делаю вот так, но не получается ничего, хоть убейся. И так и сяк, никак :(

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_weight="7">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_background"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/pink"
    app:tabBackground="@color/toolbar_background"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/pink"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:layout_weight="7"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="79"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7">

    <ru.albatros.mp3.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/panel_art"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_art"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/panel_toggle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:src="@drawable/panel_play"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/panel_art"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/panel_toggle"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:layout_below="@id/track_name"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`Toolbar`, `TabLayout`, `ViewPager` и `Layout` я выровнил по весу. В нижнем `Layout` поставил один влево, другой вправо между ними `Layout`, но получается вот что. Левый `ImageView` сжатый, правого вообще нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это ужас какой-то, 100% дело в какой то мелочи, но я не могу найти ее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение :)

Я сделал высоту панели по высоте тулбара, тоже самое провернул и с квадратами.